# Spinnaker pipeline name environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I've spinnaker with kubernetes manifest v2. Now, I'm creating spinnaker pipeline with manifest files in which I'd like to have namespace named as **applicationName-pipelineName**.

I'm looking for spinnaker environment variable for pipeline name which I can use in manifest file to would append in file.

Ex. I'm using docker registry latest tag as
`imageName:${trigger['tag']}`

similarly something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: appName-${pipelineName}
```

please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check official docs? https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/kubernetes-v2/parameterize-manifests/ and https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During pipeline runtime you have following parameters available:
`${execution.id}` - unique id of execution;
`${execution.name}` - name of pipeline used during creation;
`${execution.pipelineConfigId}` - unique id for pipeline across whole Spinnaker  instance, it also could be set to something meaningful if you create pipeline using API.

Do not forget that namespace's name is very sensitive to case and non-alphanumerical symbols. Such functions like `#alphanumerical(string)` and `${java.lang.String.toLowerCase()}` will be very helpful.

You may find this reference useful - [Pipeline Expression Reference](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/expressions/).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working `${execution.name}` as expected. I've gone through this document before https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/ but I didn't understood how to use it. Is it the same link you've used or if there any other please share for further reference. Thanks.

Comment: @JaydeepSoni I have added link to reference, but you will need to spend some time with pipeline json to understand how it really works.